# "One or more multiply defined symbols found". Static and friend function

Tags: c++, friend-function, one-definition-rule, interface-class

I'm trying to use `interface` classes and I have the following `class` structure:

IBase.h:

```
#pragma once
class IBase
{
protected:
    virtual ~IBase() = default;

public:
    virtual void Delete() = 0;

    IBase& operator=(const IBase&) = delete;
};
```

IQuackable.h:

```
#ifndef IQUACKABLE
#define IQUACKABLE

#include "IBase.h"
#include <iostream>


class IQuackable : public IBase
{
protected:
    IQuackable() = default;
    ~IQuackable() = default;

public:
    virtual void Quack() = 0;

    static IQuackable* CreateInstance();
};

#endif //
```

MallardDuck.h:

```
#pragma once
#include "IQuackable.h"

class MallardDuck : public IQuackable
{
private:
    MallardDuck();

protected:
    ~MallardDuck();

public:
    void Delete() override;
    void Quack() override;

    friend IQuackable* IQuackable::CreateInstance();
};
```

MallardDuck.cpp:

```
#include "MallardDuck.h"

MallardDuck::MallardDuck() {}

MallardDuck::~MallardDuck() {}

void MallardDuck::Delete() { delete this; }

void MallardDuck::Quack()
{
    std::cout << "Quack!\n";
}

IQuackable* IQuackable::CreateInstance()
{
    return static_cast<IQuackable*>(new MallardDuck());
}
```

Also I've created class RedHeadDuck.h and .cpp with the same declaration and definition as MallardDuck.

And, finaly, main class code:

```
#include "MallardDuck.h"
#include "RedHeadDuck.h"

int main()
{
    IQuackable* mallardDuck = MallardDuck::CreateInstance();
    IQuackable* redHeadDuck = RedHeadDuck::CreateInstance();

    mallardDuck->Quack();
    redHeadDuck->Quack();
}
```

And here I got two errors:

---

> *LNK2005  "public: static class IQuackable * __cdecl IQuackable::CreateInstance(void)" (?CreateInstance@IQuackable@@SAPAV1@XZ) already defined in MallardDuck.obj".*

*LNK1169 "one or more multiply defined symbols found".*

---

As I find out, the problem is in double definition, but how it fix?

I've read about Header guards, but, as I understood, it can't help in this case. Also people write about inline functions, but I've not realized how it may be used here.

What can I do?

Comment: `{ delete this; }`... ouch.

Comment: Remove `IQuackable::CreateInstance()` and create `MallardDuck::CreateInstance()` and `RedHeadDuck::CreateInstance()`? You cannot have two definitions for single function, even if they are in different files. `static` member functions or not, it will not work.

Comment: `MallardDuck::CreateInstance()` is actually `IQuackable::CreateInstance()`...

Comment: `RedHeadDuck::CreateInstance();` is probably the same, so the duplicated one.

Comment: According to your description, there *are* two definitions of `IQuackable::CreateInstance()`, in separate files. What is the point of this function?

Comment: @Jarod42 maybe it's supposed to be a comment `// TODO delete this`. I know our legacy code base is full of these comments xD

Comment: @JHBonarius: Not sure what that comment would mean either... Anyway, with smart pointers, no need to write `new`/`delete` :)

Comment: @Jarod42 In my case it sadly means that prototyping code has made it to production. Written long ago by developers that have long left. Anyhow, offtopic. Deleting `this` is not good, no. The OP needs to read a [good book](https://stackoverflow.com/a/388282)

Answer (score 0):

### Goals

I suppose these are what you are trying to obtain by adopting all the complicated patterns:

1. interface, i.e., "multiple types, same set of methods"
2. *some sort of* [abstract factory pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern), i.e., you want a "instantiator" who provides a static method (which is not very different from a global function) to call, and returns instances of derived classes
3. prohibit users from directly calling the ctors of derived classes
4. take care of the dtors by implementing the `Delete()` method

### Requirement 1-3

There are at least 3 ways to meet requirement 1-3, as explained below:

#### 1. Derived classes hiding static method of their base

This is the easiest way, and it's fully capable of current `main.cpp`. Derived classes *can* override static methods of their base class.

In file `MallardDuck.h` and `RedHeadDuck.h`:

```cpp
    // Replace this:
    // friend IQuackable* IQuackable::CreateInstance();

    // With this:
    static IQuackable* CreateInstance();
```

In file `MallardDuck.cpp` (and `RedHeadDuck.cpp` similarly):

```cpp
// Replace this:
// IQuackable* IQuackable::CreateInstance() {
//     return static_cast<IQuackable*>(new MallardDuck());
// }

// With this:
IQuackable* MallardDuck::CreateInstance() {
    return new MallardDuck();
}
```

The problem with this is that: other derived classes that don't override and hide `CreateInstance()` will still expose `IQuackable::CreateInstance()` as a "fallback". Thus:

1. if you don't actually implement `IQuackable::CreateInstance()` (so far, you don't have to), then once it is called via a derived class, the code won't compile and won't give a reason that's comprehensible to others; or
2. if you choose to implement it, you'd better throw an exception within it, which may surprise your user; otherwise you would have to return a `nullptr` or something, which is the worst practice in C++ (that's what we do in C since it has no language-level support for error handling; any C++ function that cannot fulfill its job should never return).

Either way is not elegant.

#### 2. Adopt abstract factory pattern

This pattern requires a cooperating "factory class", which is abstract; then whenever you derive a concrete quackable, derive also its factory.

In your case you'll need to sketch out a `IQuackableFactory`, exposing `IQuackableFactory::CreateInstance()`, then derive a `MallardDuckFactory` and a `RedHeadDuckFactory`.

There are plenty of good examples already, so I won't demonstrate here.

#### 3. Feature injection by using CRTP

There's yet another way of doing things. By `CreateInstance()` you're actually providing a "Give me an instance of this class!" feature. Typically we use the CRTP ([curiously recurring template pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern)) to "inject" a certain feature into a class.

First write this file `EnableCreateInstance.hpp`:

```cpp
#ifndef _ENABLECREATEINSTANCE_HPP_
#define _ENABLECREATEINSTANCE_HPP_

template <class T>
struct EnableCreateInstance {
    static T* CreateInstance() { return new T(); }
};

#endif //_ENABLECREATEINSTANCE_HPP_
```

Then in `MallardDuck.h`:

```cpp
// Add:
#include "EnableCreateInstance.hpp"

class MallardDuck : public IQuackable, public EnableCreateInstance<MallardDuck> {
private:
    MallardDuck();

    friend class EnableCreateInstance<MallardDuck>;

    ...
```

In file `RedHeadDuck.h` do the similar: include header, **publicly** inherit `EnableCreateInstance<RedHeadDuck>`, and declare `EnableCreateInstance<RedHeadDuck>` as friend class.

This provides more flexibility: you're still providing an interface `CreateInstance()`, but in a less "aggressive" way: derived classes have their freedom to choose whether or not to provide `CreateInstance()`. If they do, just inherit and (if ctor made private) declare friendship; if not, omit the additional inheritance.

### Requirement 4

Well, actually you *can* use `delete this` in non-static **non-dtor** method. But:

1. You must ensure (which can be difficult) that no more access to the deleted object's data members **or virtual functions** are made, otherwise it causes undefined behaviors;
2. You leave your users with dangling pointers to the deleted object.

So, we seldom provide such "deleters" in modern C++. You can get all the benefits it may provide through [smart pointers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_pointer), plus the ability to avoid UBs and so much more.